# Restart scrapy for each url in list

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I am trying to run a scrapy bot that will run the spider repeatedly for each url given in a list. The code that I have written till now is the following

```
def run_spider(url_list,allowed_list):
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    d = runner.crawl('scraper',start_urls=url_list, allowed_domains=allowed_list)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()



for start, allowed in zip(start_url,allowedUrl):
    url_list = []
    allowed_list = []
    url_list.append(start)
    allowed_list.append(allowed)
    print(type(url_list),type(allowed_list))
    run_spider(url_list,allowed_list)
```

The spider itself is running fine on the first url but as soon as the loop hits its gives the error `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`, Thefull traceback is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\brox\Crawler\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    run_spider(url_list,allowed_list)
  File "C:\brox\Crawler\main.py", line 24, in run_spider
    reactor.run()
  File "C:\brox\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1282, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\brox\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1262, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "C:\brox\Crawler\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 765, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I am following the method that is described in the docs but how do I restart the spider for each item in the loop. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

P:S:: The spider bot in itself is working fine when simply passing the allowed domains and start urls

Answer (score 1):

To get your code working, you'll have to rearrange your `reactor.run()` and `reactor.stop()` logic. Here is an example of a way you can solve your problem:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults
from twisted.internet import reactor

def run_spider(url_list, allowed_list):
    """
    :returns: Deferred
    """
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    return runner.crawl('scraper', start_urls=url_list, allowed_domains=allowed_list)

d_list = []
for start, allowed in zip(start_url, allowedUrl):
    # ... your logic ...
    # Append the deferred into a list.
    d_list.append(run_spider(url_list, allowed_list))

# "Join"
results = gatherResults(d_list)
# Stop the reactor after all the sites are scraped or a failure occurs
results.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

`run_spider()` returns a [`Deferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html). In the loop, append the `Deferred` into a list and "join" all the list or stop processing when a failure occurs (read [`gatherResults`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#gatherResults)). Once the sites are all scraped, the reactor will stop.

Search the web for `ReactorNotRestartable` as this has been explained many times before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to scrapy. But I would write this crawler without restarting the crawler (which is problematic because it requires restarting the reactor). Something like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidery'
    allowed_domains = ['allowed_list']
    start_urls = url_list
    
    def parse(self, response):
       #here is what you want to scrape

crawler = CrawlerProcess()
crawler.crawl(MySpider)
crawler.start()
```

I hope that should do it!

Comment: As I described in my question that the spider bot is running fine, I need a method to stop and rerun the scrapy for each url.